# Здравствуйте не могу понять условия задачи

Tags: javascript

Напиши скрипт создания и очистки коллекции элементов. Пользователь вводит количество элементов в input и нажимает кнопку Создать, после чего рендерится коллекция. Нажатием кнопки Очистить, коллекция элементов очищается.

```
<div id="controls">
   <input type="number" min="1" max="100" step="1" />
   <button type="button" data-create>Create</button>
   <button type="button" data-destroy>Destroy</button>
</div>

<div id="boxes"></div>
```

Создай функцию createBoxes(amount), которая принимает один параметр – число. Функция создает столько `<div>`, сколько указано в amount и добавляет их в `div#boxes`.

Размеры самого первого `<div>` – `30px` на `30px`.
Каждый элемент после первого должен быть шире и выше предыдущего на `10px`.
Все элементы должны иметь случайный цвет фона в формате HEX. Используй готовую функцию getRandomHexColor для получения цвета.

```
function getRandomHexColor() {
   return `#${Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215)
     .toString(16)
     .padStart(6, 0)}`;
}
```

Создай функцию `destroyBoxes()`, которая очищает содержимое `div#boxes`, таким образом удаляя все созданные элементы.

Comment: И что конкретно не понятно?

Comment: как решить эту задачу

Comment: что то понятно а что-то нет , хотелось чтобы кто-то обьяснил

Comment: Там по факту уже всё расписано, осталось перевести эти действия в JS, для этого конечно же нужны хотя бы основы языка. Единственное, что не рассказано в этом задании - это про взаимодействие с элементами в блоке `#controls`, но это уже пол беды.

Comment: я пока что это написал

Comment: const refs = {
 controlsEl: document.querySelector('#controls  input'),
 createEl: document.querySelector('button[data-create]'),
 destroy: document.querySelector('button[data-destroy]'),
 boxesEl: document.getElementById('boxes')
}
console.log(refs);

function getRandomHexColor() {
  return `#${Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215)
    .toString(16)
    .padStart(6, 0)}`;
}

refs.

Comment: та есть input и две кнопки в водимое чесло в инпут и после нажатия кнопки create создается квадратики разных цветов рандомно

Comment: Этот код лучше поместить в ваш вопрос.

Comment: Я просто не знаю с чего начать

Answer (score 0):

По задаче такая реализация.

```js
const refs = {
  amountEl: document.querySelector('#controls input'),
  createEl: document.querySelector('button[data-create]'),
  destroyEl: document.querySelector('button[data-destroy]'),
  boxesEl: document.querySelector('#boxes')
}

function createBoxes(amount) {
  for(var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    var elem = document.createElement('div');
    
    elem.style.width = 30 + (10 * i)+'px';
    elem.style.height = 30+'px';
    elem.style.backgroundColor = getRandomHexColor();
    
    refs.boxesEl.append(elem);
  }
}

refs.createEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var amount = refs.amountEl.value;
  if(amount > 0) {
    createBoxes(amount);
  }
});

refs.destroyEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
  refs.boxesEl.innerHTML = '';
});


function getRandomHexColor() {
  return `#${Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215)
    .toString(16)
    .padStart(6, 0)}`;
}
```

```html
<div id="controls">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="100" step="1" />
  <button type="button" data-create>Create</button>
  <button type="button" data-destroy>Destroy</button>
</div>

<div id="boxes"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо щас буду розбиратся с этим

Comment: а так не проходит ? boxesEl: document.getElementById('boxes')

Comment: @YuriStarchenko, пройдёт. Чтобы не путаться сделал `querySelector()`, т.к. остальные такие же.

Comment: спасибо. Ты реально крут мне еще разбиратся и разбиратся

Comment: Вопрос, а как всё сделать за одну операцию, а не на каждой итерации рендерить по одному?

Comment: @YuriStarchenko, в идеале именно так, другие варианты лишь колхоз.